# Потоки в PySide

Tags: python, многопоточность, pyqt, pyside6, qtimer

Есть код, который запускает приложение, затем запускает поток, который каждую секунду меняет размер виджета в приложении:

```
class UsageLine(QFrame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setGeometry(10, 55, 10, 4)
        self.setStyleSheet('background-color: rgb(17, 125, 187); border-radius: 2px;')
        self.animation = QPropertyAnimation(self, b"size", EasingCurve=QEasingCurve.OutCubic)

    def set(self, percentage):
        self.animation.setEndValue(QSize(percentage * 3, 4))
        self.animation.start()


class GUI(QMainWindow):
    # something
    self.cpu_usage = UsageLine(cpu_usage_frame)
    Thread(target=self.dashboard_controller, daemon=True).start()
    self.show()

    def dashboard_controller(self):
        while True:
            if self.currentSpace.currentIndex() == 0:
                self.cpu_usage.set(50)
            sleep(1)
```

Функция `set` вызывается, но анимации нет?

[**Тут**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45175427/pyqt5-run-function-after-displaying-window) есть что-то похожее, но не понятно как это использовать?

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В *Qt* достаточно своих средств,
которые обеспечивают независимый от платформы способ управления потоками.

Но для вашего фрагмента, который вы показали, дополнительные потоки не нужны. 
Вам достаточно использовать `QTimer`.

Класс `QTimer` предоставляет повторяющиеся и однократные таймеры. 
Больше https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimer.html

Вот одно из возможных решений:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class UsageLine(QFrame):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        
#        self.setGeometry(10, 55, 10, 4)
        self.setGeometry(10, 55, 0, 4)
        
        self.setStyleSheet('background-color: rgb(17, 125, 187); border-radius: 2px;')
        self.animation = QPropertyAnimation(
            self, 
            b"size", 
            easingCurve=QEasingCurve.OutCubic
        )
        self.animation.setDuration(1000)  

    def set(self, percentage):
        self.animation.setEndValue(QSize(percentage * 3, 4))
        self.animation.start()


class GUI(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.centralWidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)
        
        self.percentage = 0
        
        # something
        self.cpu_usage = UsageLine(self.centralWidget)         #(cpu_usage_frame)
#    Thread(target=self.dashboard_controller, daemon=True).start()
 
        self.timer = QTimer()
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.dashboard_controller)
        
        QTimer.singleShot(10, self.timer_start)

    def timer_start(self):
        self.timer.start(1000)

    def dashboard_controller(self):
#        while True:
# ???            if self.currentSpace.currentIndex() == 0:

        self.percentage += 10
        self.cpu_usage.set(self.percentage)
        if self.percentage >= 100:
            self.timer.stop()
   
#            sleep(1)
            
            
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = GUI()
    window.resize(320, 150)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]